# Getting value out of textarea on a twig template

Tags: symfony, templates, overriding, sylius

I am working with sylius e-commerce and I'm very new to symfony2 and sylius, I am exploring a lot but sometimes I am facing problems like I have today, well my problem is next, I overrided show.html.twig and I placed (added by myself) textarea on a content of a page, and now I would like to ask you guys, how could I get value out of that textarea and to store it to some var or something like that in case I want to do something with that value. It is impossible to write standard php code inside of a twig, smth like:

because there is not html, head and body tags so I can place my php code inside..

Here is content of my show.html.twig

[image]

thx

Comment: why don't you want to put this textarea into a form?

Comment: You can get the value of the text area in your controller once the form is submitted. 
It would be better to explain whta you are trying to achieve as you might be using the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

i see that you want to override the cart item form (or maybe another but it's the same solution)

To override the sylius_cart_item form and add a field in this form you must create a form type like that:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Form\Type\CartItemType as BaseCartItemType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class CartItemType extends BaseCartItemType
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('comment', 'textarea', [
                'label' => 'sylius.form.cart_item.comment',
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

override the model

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Model;

use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\CartItem as BaseCartItem;

class OrderItem extends BaseCartItem
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $comment;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $comment
     */
    public function setComment($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }
}
```

and add the following in your config.yml

```
sylius_cart:
    resources:
        cart_item:
            classes:
                form:
                    default: AppBundle\Form\Type\CartItemType
```

create AppBunde/Resources/config/doctrine/model/OrderItem.orm.xml with the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                                      http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd"
                  xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping">

    <mapped-superclass name="AppBundle\Model\OrderItem" table="sylius_order_item">
        <field type="string" name="comment" column="comment" />
    </mapped-superclass>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

and add in your view:

```
{{ form_widget(form.comment) }}
```

and add in your AppBundle.php

```
class AppBundle extends AbstractResourceBundle
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSupportedDrivers()
    {
        return [
            SyliusResourceBundle::DRIVER_DOCTRINE_ORM,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getModelNamespace()
    {
        return 'AppBundle\Model';
    }
}
```

and finally the doctrine command to update the database

app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

The solution that i provide might not be the best but it work.

You can do that with most of the sylius forms. To see a full configuration your can look at Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/app/sylius.yml
Also i advise you to look at the ResourceBundle doc http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/index.html